# ng-click of angularJS is not displaying anything when buttons are clicked

Tags: angularjs

angular js code:

```
      appModule.controller('dcrlistingCtrl', ['$scope','$modal','$state','$rootScope','loginService', 'servicePOST', 'appConstants','sessionService', '$http', 
      function($scope,$modal,$state,$rootScope,loginService, servicePOST, appConstants,sessionService, $http) {   

        $scope.doctors = function() {
            alert("Doctors");
        };

        $scope.pharmacists = function() {
            alert("pharmacists");
        };

        $scope.stockists = function() {
           alert("pharmacists");
        };

      alert("trial");

      $scope.contact="Doctors";


            $scope.doctors=
    [
      {"patch":"BARIJPUR", "doctor":["RAMA SENA", "SMRITI IRANI","JAGDISH NAIR"]}, 
      {"patch":"Anna", "doctor":["ASHISH NAIK", "SMRITI IRANI", "SAIRAJ NAIK"]}, 
      {"patch":"Peter","doctor":["RATAN PANDEY", "RAMAN SHIVOLKAR"]}
    ];




      }])
```

html code:

```
       <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary "  ng-click=="doctors()"><b>Doctor</b></button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary " ng-click=="pharmacists()" ><b>Pharmacist</b></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary " ng-click=="stockists()" ><b>Stockist</b></button>
```

---

any angularJS experet here? need help!

the alert("trial"); is shown!

But when i click these buttons, no alert is shown! 
why is that so?
any help and advice or changes are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the double equals after each ng-click.

The following:

```
ng-click=="stockists()"
```

should be

```
ng-click="stockists()"
```

Answer (score 0):

> The alert("trial") is being shown because it is not within the scope
>   of any click function of yours rather in the scope of controller where
>   the alert("trial") gets called once you are into the view which has
>   that particular controller. And, the matter of fact where your click
>   function is not working is because you have got 2 equals(==) in
>   `ng-click`.

```
<button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary "  ng-click="doctors()"><b>Doctor</b></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary " ng-click="pharmacists()" ><b>Pharmacist</b></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary " ng-click="stockists()" ><b>Stockist</b></button>
```